# matlab how to delete rows using logical index

Tags: matlab, matrix, compare

I have a matrix:

> > A = [ 4567 345; 45 6787; 3345 NaN; 87 6787]

and a vector

> > B = [ 4567; 45; 8976 ]

I want to compare A and B and delete in A all the rows that do not have at least one number which is included in matrix B.

The resulting matrix would be:

```
[ 4567   345;

  45    6787 ]
```

Here is the code:

```
idx=ismember(A(:,1:2),B); %%create a logical index in order to see if A includes elements of B

n = length(A)
for i=1:n
   if (idx(i,1)==0)& (idx(i,2)==0)
       A(i,:)=[];
   end
end
```

However I got this error:

```
Index of element to remove exceeds matrix dimensions.
```

I tried with another solution but I get the same error.

```
n = length(A)
for i=1:n
     if (find(idx(i,1)==0))& (find(idx(i,2)==0))
     A(i,:)=[];
     end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need a loop in this logical indexing task:

```
ismember(A,B)
ans =
     1     0
     1     0
     0     0
     0     0
```

All you need is to keep those rows with at least one match with `any(...,2)`:

```
idx = any(ismember(A,B),2)
idx =
     1
     1
     0
     0
```

The result:

```
A(idx,:)
ans =
        4567         345
          45        6787
```

The **error** is caused by the fact that your loop runs from `1:n` but you are removing rows from the matrix making it effectively shorter than `n`.

Answer (score 0):

```
A = [ 4567 345; 45 6787; 3345 NaN; 87 6787]
B = [ 8976; 45; 4567 ]
z = sum(ismember(A,B)');
NewMatrix=[];
for i = 1:length(z)
    if z(i)>= 1
        newMatrix = A(i,:);
        NewMatrix=[NewMatrix;newMatrix];
    end
end
NewMatrix
```